# Reverse that Math function

Tags: c#, c++, math

I need to reverse a function with hard Math operations, I'm asking here to check if it's even possible, eventually for help.

```
    public static UInt32 Func_4(UInt32 P, UInt32 X, UInt32 G)
    {
        UInt64 result = 1;
        UInt64 mult = G;
        if (X == 0)
            return 1;
        while (X != 0)
        {
            if ((X & 1) != 0)
                result = (mult * result) % P;
            X = X >> 1;
            mult = (mult * mult) % P;
        }
        return (UInt32)result;
    }
```

**By "Reversing" I mean this: I know G, I know P, I know the result. I need X.**

I tried to translate it again this morning while my mind was clear, but I failed. Is it even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your expected inputs to the inverse? Which of P, X, and G are you looking to get back?

Comment: It would help if you show the algorithm you hope to do.  Also, if you know the result and don't know X, then why pass in X? Pass in the result as a parameter.

Comment: James: I think he has r = f(p, x, g) and wants a function x = h(p, r, g).

Comment: @Ben,I need X.

@James,X by default is random everytime you use the whole algoritm.I need to get that random number always.I know the other two,they are static.I also know the result.I have to reverse that function and then put the result and the other two parameters I know to get X.

Comment: What does the function compute?  Let's start there. :)

Comment: Its used in the security between a TCP client and TCP server.What the server does is actually this,it finds X.There's no other way to find it,since all the client sends is the result from that function.The server knows the static values(P and G) from the previous packet,so it finds X and responds back to the TCP Client.It can't be impossible!

Comment: @John: you're probably thinking of SSL, not TCP (which has no security), and I think you're mistaken in thinking that the server finds X. There are ways to do meaningful things with this algorithm even without inverting it, for instance the "Diffie-Hellman key exchange" protocol (a Google search will give you plenty of reading material if you want).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like your `Func_4()` function calculates *G<sup>X</sup> mod P*. What you're asking for is a solution to the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem, but no efficient algorithm is known.

Comment: However, if the poster does solve this problem, I've got this RSA system I'm trying to break...

Comment: the "mod" is the problem. You won't break this ever. 5 mod 2 has the same result as 7 mod 2 and 9 mod 4 and so on. You can't determine the input based on the output. There is an infinity of input combinations that result in the desired output. Go to sleep.

Comment: Exactly. You're not supposed to get X. You're supposed to check whether the client *knew* the correct x by sending it different G and P, and check if their results agree with yours. But at no point is x supposed to be transmitted.

Answer (score 5):

well,

working through this by hand for:

P=5, X=0b0000 1110, G=7

P=5, X=0b0001 1110, G=7

P=5, X=0b0011 1110, G=7

P=5, X=0b0111 1110, G=7

etc, i think you see the pattern

all have the same return value for result (4)...

therefore any attempt to reverse this to get a value for X would have multiple possible values for X..

depending what you actually need out of this thing, this may not really matter...

whats the context of this thing?

Answer (score 4):

Since the modulo operator is in play, you can tell immediately that the function is not bijective: for a fixed P and G, different x's may return the same result.

But the function *is* bijective for a limited domain of x.  Just like atan, asin, sqrt, .... produce a whole set of values, when you limit the domain, you can pick the correct one.

At first sight, what the function does, for a very large P, is,

The product of G<sup>(2i*x[i])</sup>, where x[i] is the i'th bit of x (starting with bit 0 as least significant).

This means that given a large P (larger than Prod(G<sup>2i</sup>), for  x=0x1111...111), you can reverse the function.  It also seems that the function was *designed* not to be reversible for smaller P's.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like i = (g**x) mod p. That means there may be more than one x

Comment: Yeah,X = X << 1 ,everytime you step the loop.
Does that mean its impossible?

Comment: Not impossible, just that there are multiple answers (and not due to the << but due to the %). 

Is this fast enough for you?...

x=0; do { if (Func_4(P,x,G)==I) then return x; x++; } while (x!=0);

Answer (score 1):

pseduo algorithm

R = pow(G,X) mod P

ie) there exists one Q which is  R + P * Q = pow (G,X)

In reverse,  Check Y for all Q from 0 to UINT32((MAXUINT32-R)/P),

Y =  log ( R + P * Q ) / log (G)

and if the value Y does not have fractions, then they are the Set of multiple "X" answers to your problem.

Assume X1 is the first X value which does not have fractions and X2 is the second X Value which does not have fractions. Then Set of all X can be given in the equation X(S) = X1 + (X2-X1) * S  where S=0 to UINT32( (MAXUINT32-X1) / (X2-X1) ).

That is due to if 
1= Pow(G,T) mod P and then Pow(G,X+T) mod P = Pow(G,X) mod P * Pow(G,T) mod P which is 
also Pow(G,X) mod P. Hence X, X+T, X+2T, X+3T... all will have same values..

Answer (score 0):

I seriously think you're abusing this algorithm. From your description, and from looking at the algorithm, it's pretty clear that this is designed to go forward only. Think of it as computing a checksum of X using keys P and G.